# Development environment in Visual Studio using Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop

Platform: Yosemite 10.10.4; MacbookPro 15" Retina (mid-2015).
Questions regarding development on MacOS:

1. Does Visual Studio for MacOS have all development and debugging capabilities (especially in C, C++, and C# languages), like which Visual Studio for Windows has ?
2. General question - what are capability differences between Professional and Enterprise edition (of Visual Studio) ?
3. Visual Studio online installation - when is this manner preferred, and what are its cons and pros?
4. [This link](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) gives download of free version for students. Clicking on it - I see there is no 64-bit version, and the existing 32-bit, and 32-bit-Web-installer [don't make "Download" button pressable](https://www.dreamspark.com/product/product.aspx?productid=93&cmpid=w_vs_dsv_ds_728x90_eng). Is there a working option to download and install it (appears there as Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 4)?
5. Is Visual Studio running smoothly (performance, drivers, development capabilities), while installed -> on Windows -> on Parallels (virtual machine) ?
6. Is Visual Studio running smoothly (performance, drivers, development capabilities), while installed -> on Windows, using Bootcamp as dual-boot utility ("pure" Windows)?
7. What is the best combination-steps solution (convenience, performance, capabilities) for developing in Visual Studio on Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Visual Studio Code is a glorified text editor
2. I am not certain, but usually enterprise is for volume licensing, although there may be other features given in enterprise not present in professional.
3. I think this is personal preference, pros are you don't need to burn a DVD or mount an ISO, and rather than one large file download it is lots of little files, and I believe it is resumable. Cons are you need to be online, and you do not have a backup that you can burn to DVD in case the installer goes down for whatever reason.
4. The 32 bit version is the only one that exists as far as I know, and it is what I have always used on my MacBook Pro
5. I have personally used it in VMWare Fusion on windows 7 & 8.1 pro with good stability, and a few people I know report the same with parallels
6. Yes, this runs very well & I have had no issues using this, I use this as my main setup as my mac is a tad slow with VMWare on 8.1 pro (My preferred windows version)
7. If you have a mac that runs your favourite windows version well in parallels, then use this method would be my advise. If you have boot camp regardless for games etc, then use that, or use boot camp if you experience large amounts of slowness when running windows in parallels and OS X at the same time.

My experience is from a late 2007 MacBook Pro with 4GB RAM.
Hope this helps answer your question